# Show a function is a constant function

Tags: real-analysis

[image]
My friend used f prime to solve this question, but it seems the question didn’t state that function f is differentiable. So we are not sure whether our solution is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to show, that $f$ must be differentiable:

$$\sqrt{|f(a)-f(b)|} \leq \sin |a-b| \Rightarrow |f(a)-f(b)| \leq \sin^2 |a-b| $$
Now, note that

- $\sin x \leq x $ on $(0,\pi) \Rightarrow \sin^2 |a-b| \leq |a-b|^2$

But this means, that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous

$$\Rightarrow |f(a)-f(b)| \leq |a-b|^2 \Rightarrow \left| \frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b} \right|\leq |a-b| \Rightarrow $$

$f$ is differentiable and $f'(x) = 0$ on $(0,\pi)$.